# How to ask my old boss who started his own company for a job?

Tags: new-job, manager

Background: I currently work at a small I.T. company that I have been at for 1.5 years. When I started there was about 30 staff. It was founded by 2 guys a couple years before then. The founders of the company retired early (in their mid 40's) about a year ago, and the company is still doing really well. We have over 60 staff now.

I heard through the grape vine that the 2 founders who "retired" did take some time off work, but have since started their own company again. There was also another guy from my place who have left, and rumours around the office say this guy left the company to work for the 2 original founders again on their new business.

I got on really well with one of the founders. I have his personal email address and want to ask him for a job, but I dont know how.

I need to ask if the rumours are true that he does have a new business - and if he would consider me for a new position. I'm also looking to move from a developer to a project manager but I'm happy to try new roles.

Question: How can I email him and ask him these things and ask him to consider me for a position?

Comment: But im not sure if I should mention 'rumours'.

Comment: I wouldn't call them rumors, so just say you heard they're hiring and give reasons why you want to leave this company and work for them.  Other than that, we don't really know enough about your relationship with these former founders and how they may feel about poaching employees from their former company.

Answer (score 3):

Email him. Say you heard that he is starting a new company. Don't call them rumors. Ask him if he needs someone with your skills, remind him of your skills. If you are good at what you do he will be happy to hear from you, even if he doesn't have a use for you right now.

Your caution about sending an email makes me think people told you this new company was a secret. Don't worry about that. If he is a successful entrepreneur he will realize that he can't keep something like this a secret.

(This is based on the norms of the US startup workplace)